# Tesseract OCR, pre-processing for subtitles extraction

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I am trying to do OCR on some grayscale video frames using tesseract. OCR for subtitles is trickier than document extraction as the text is over the background frame and the background introduce a lot of noise and can have a similar color as the subtitles. The font are genererally anti-aliased, which makes it harder to extract only the text with thresholding, and for even more complexity, the frames I am working on are grayscale and have been downscaled.

Here is a sample:

[image: frame for OCR]

The result I get after thresholding at 220:
[image]

It is quite alright already, but as you can see there is big chunks of the background remaining and Tesseact just can't dissociate it from the text.

There are techniques with some assumptions, like removing after thresholding black regions that touche the border, assuming the text doesn't, but this is quite specific and doesn't apply to a lot of case.

What I am looking for is a method that I can apply live and will generalise to other frames.

Comment: Did you make any headway with this? I'm trying to solve a similar problem.

Comment: I did not solve it but I found a way to extract a mask that improves results a little in average. I do a morphological "Edge In" (like the one in image magick), followed by a series of `n=4` erosions and then `n` dilations, I apply then OTSU thresholding to get the mask.
In some cases, the result of the "Edge In" transformation gives better OCR results (you can even apply the mask on the result on it to remove some of the noise).

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question so I'm putting it in a comment BUT specifying minimum font size might help. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/eVVrKz8T07w